# Can I use two USB gamepads to play games in FCE Ultra?

Tags: hardware, emulation

I want to buy a couple USB game pads to use with NES emulator FCE Ultra. What I can't find out, is if I have two game pads connected, will FCEU differentiate between them? i.e. map each game pad to each player, or will both game pads button A generate the same key code?

BTW I'm looking at the [Genius MaxFire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FJQ1VS), Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play using two gamepads, yes. There is a tab in GFCE UltraX (recommended over FCE Ultra) called "Input" where you can map the buttons to the buttons on the pad. A on one controller will not register as A on the other controller. GFCE UltraX (gfeux) can be installed in Ubuntu by running `sudo apt-get install gfeux` in a terminal, or simply clicking this [link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gfceux) (doesn't work in Chrome).

As for the controller, I don't know if it works well in Ubuntu or not (most do), but it seems quite expensive for what it does. If you're open for suggestions, I'd recommend taking a look at a [Saitek P380](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ISTYAG). It costs a fraction as much, has two analog sticks, an omnidirectional d-pad, 4 regular buttons + 4 shoulder buttons and start and select buttons. I have one and it works perfectly in Ubuntu.

Comment: Just what I was hoping to hear! I'll check out the P380, it costs 2x more my side, but I do like the analog sticks + shoulder buttons.